# How can I generate an elegant (academic) static CV web page?

Tags: cv, software, website, online-resource

A friend of mine has a personal website, including a CV laid out on a page of that site (i.e. not a downloadable PDF/ODT/DOC) document. I want to help them spruce up that page somewhat.

Now, this could be made into a more complicated question if I said I also wanted the style of the CV to match the basic style of pages on that website, but let's forget about that for now, and just ask: Is there a utility, or web app, which can be given a CV (in any format - in a JSON file, by feeding into some web forms etc.) and lay it out elegantly in static HTML+CSS?

Notes:

- The result must have no Javascript, animation or animation-like effects (i.e. no "onmouseover", no CSS hover pseudo-elements etc.). So, "static" in the strong sense of the word.
- Naturally I'm interested in producing an academic CV, but if I had something for a non-academic CV I would probably be able to adapt the generated HTML for my needs, or whatever.

Comment: My first instinct would be to copy and paste it by hand, so I can adjust everything to my taste in HTML directly. Why do you want to convert it automatically? Does it have to be updated frequently from another master document?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Not sure I understand what you mean by "copy and paste it". Paste where? Do you mean editing by hand? Of course that's possible, but I was hoping something reasonable is available without going to that trouble yourself. And one can always embellish by hand, so starting with a nicer baseline for that would be good to. Also, the CV needs to be updated occasionally, and I would rather my friend be able to avoid HTML + CSS editing by hand as much as is possible.

Comment: Depends what you use to edit HTML, but in the worst case if your editor doesn't do copy-paste a ODT->HTML converter will work. But if you don't want your friend to edit HTML by hand, are you sure that a static website is the best solution? Wordpress, a wiki, a static website generator working with Markdown, all seem better choices.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: 1. Why would I convert an ODT? That's not what I asked about. 2. A static website is what my friend has, I'm not going to change that.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the input format is then. How would your friend want to write their CV? How do they deal with formatting, for instance the occasional word in italic or diacritic? Does the input need to be shared with another version of the CV? Or is it just for the convenience of not writing HTML directly?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: The input format will be whatever the web page generator tool needs. Right now, the CV is inconsistently formatted anyway. No, the input does not need to be shared with another version of the CV. It is not just the convenience of not writing HTML - it's the convenience of not having to format, lay out and style the CV.

Comment: You can find templates from site generators like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) and [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), for example [al-folio](https://alshedivat.github.io/al-folio/) or [Hugo Academic](https://academic-demo.netlify.app/#demo).

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Those seem like website templates. They're interesting, but - I'm looking for an HTML page generator (without dynamic elements, navigation bar, sub-pages etc.)

Comment: I am not sure I understood you, those templates do generate fully static HTML pages from config/data files populated by the user. You can configure the output to be on a single page entirely if you like. There is no need to edit HTML directly anywhere unless you want to specifically customize something.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: I followed the two example links, and did not see static pages. But I'll take a closer look at how to configure them to create a fully static page. If you can describe a complete procedure - that would be an answer to this question...

Comment: I have personally only used Hugo Academic, and IMHO its [documentation](https://wowchemy.com/docs/getting-started/page-builder/) details the steps quite well. But the example site is a static site -- there is no backend, nothing is generated dynamically -- so maybe I am still misunderstanding your requirements.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: The example site is full of scripts, has a navigation bar which scrolls the content up and down etc.

Comment: I think that ORCID is what you are looking for.  However, it generates their website, not your website.  If you must control the site yourself, hand written HTML is still the way to go.

Comment: @einpoklum Usually by "static" people mean "served directly from HTML/JS/CSS files on disk, not generated on-the-fly by PHP/Python/etc (and a database) when the client requests a page". If your concept of "static" includes "no Javascript", then I suggest you make it clear.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Edited to clarify that.

Comment: @einpoklum, you can create google site

Comment: @learner: Not relevant to my needs.

Answer (score 8):

Based on your requirements, [markdown-cv](https://github.com/elipapa/markdown-cv) seems like a good option.

To use it, you write the CV in Markdown (the same format that's used in Stack Exchange), and use Jekyll to convert it to HTML. Documentation can be found [here](https://elipapa.github.io/markdown-cv/).

Screenshots for reference:

Markdown Input:
[image: Example Input]

Rendered Output:
[image: Example Output]

---

<sup>I have no affiliation with this software.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

My read on your question suggests to me that you could start at the basic level with raw HTML. Let's stay platform agnostic in your workflow.

- Get a text editor that promotes its ability to work in raw HTML.
- Review an on-line tutorial that instructs how to work with the beginning elements in raw HTML.

The most basic format will have HEADER and PARAGRAPH elements as its only input. You may eventually include LIST elements. HEADERS would include such things as Education, Experience, Publications, Proposals, and Professional Affiliations. PARAGRAPHS and LIST elements would be under these headers. All the effort at this stage is simply to copy + paste the current information into the new HTML.

Once the basic HTML works and has all the content required, move to formatting. The standard approach for this is to incorporate a CSS style header or CSS style file. Will you need lots of CSS styling commands? Not really. Define the text size and font face in each ELEMENT (HEADER, LIST, PARAGRAPH). One distinct advantage with HTML (over PDF) in this case is the ability to use relative font sizes, allowing the person viewing the page to scale for their own needs. One certain reason also to include a basic CSS is to define the view for different platforms such as desktop versus tablet versus mobile device.

Can this process be automated? Perhaps. But ... for what you are asking ... the time you would invest to find, set up, and establish proficiency with an **automated** tool is likely not minimal. Alternatively said, you can probably find a good application that will allow you to do WYSIWYG layout designs of Webpages, but it will likely over clutter the source with its own ELEMENTS (e.g. SPAN, DIV, ID), perhaps include additional page settings (e.g. width=...), and maybe even end up putting in javascript code. By implication in you posting, you are seeking to avoid this. Also alternatively said, you may find a tool that will allow you to take the current input, run it through a filter, and have it automatically produce a new HTML to a different format. Then you will likely have to learn how to design your desired filter for old -> FILTER -> new.

You may struggle with raw HTML editing to achieve elegance in the Webpage design. Be prepared at that point to need additional CSS ELEMENTS. Rather than learn how to do this with raw HTML on your own, consider two options. Find a professionally designed template that provides what you want. Copy and paste the content from the old CV to the template. Otherwise find a WYSIWYG Web page design application, layout the content in the format that you want, push a button, and get a Webpage. The advantage is that you can format in almost any way you want.

As to adding content dynamically to HTML, the only way to do this is using a server-side script method. One example is to allow your friend to keep a CSV file for publications, download that file to the Web server, and have the Web CV automatically update with the most recent list. This avoids the need for anyone to have to re-edit the raw HTML later, e.g. simply to add a new publication to a list. This step could be a later investment in your effort, but only when you have confirmed that the server can support server-side delivery of scripts.

In summary, an automated tool to convert from an existing format to a new format may not exist or simply be too much work. Doing raw HTML coding is the most future-proof approach. It may however not provide you with an end result that you consider to be the most elegant. If so, consider copying into a template or using a WYSIWYG application. Finally, assure yourself that someone else (e.g. especially the owner of the CV) will be able to reproduce the approach that you take to put content together with format, especially if you will not be responsible to update content later.

Comment: Even if you use raw HTML, I would suggest to use a CSS framework like Bootstrap, otherwise it becomes difficult to make a website that scales well to both desktop and mobile.

Comment: I've done this (many times, many sites) and my results are anything but "elegant", especially since I have a geeky mind-set, not an artistic one. It is pretty hard for a beginner, especially a geek, to get an elegant result.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Added note to support your comment.

Comment: @Buffy The OP thankfully did not ask for or define a level of elegance. We might spend hours otherwise bouncing this question on and off the list because the answers for what application to use to obtain the most elegant site will always be subjective.

Comment: Hmmm. I can't define elegance, but I know it when I see it. (Misquoting Justice Potter Stewart)

Comment: @Buffy Agreed wholeheartedly. Or as well … I cannot objectively define all parts to ugly but they sure do stand out when I see them. Yet another reason to not try to take this question in that direction.

Comment: @Buffy After some consideration, I've added a nod to using templates or WYSIWYG editors to address the OP's reference to elegance.

Comment: I understand the suggestion, but it is literally not what I asked for. "the time you would invest to find, set up, and establish consistency with an automated tool is likely not minimal." <- actually, the existing CV my friend has is not that consistent with the rest of their website, and not even entirely self-consistent... also, if the generated CV is not super-complex and convoluted, then making it consistent should not take that long. I hope.

Comment: I've change consistency to proficiency and stressed **automated** tool. You may take only a little time to do the work manually. This is indeed exactly what I recommend. I doubt that you will find an automated (as in input old, press button, output new) application that does what you want in a fully automated way (as in without you needing to work at something manually anyway) or in an easier way than doing the translation manually.